# How can I conditionally pass a value to a with variable in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm looking to pass a value to a variable based on a condition in my code. Here's the pseudo code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{% include "includes/template.html" with info=if condition: a else: b %}
```

I'm wondering how I can accomplish this. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write the if condition outside, so:

```
{% if condition %}
  {% include "includes/template.html" with info=a %}
{% else %}
    {% include "includes/template.html" with info=b %}
{% endif %}
```

Depending on the exact condition, it might be possible to do this in a shorter way.